# RoR. Read virtual parameters passed with link_to in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, parameter-passing

I have resumes, vacancies and reactions.

I allow users to react on vacancy or resume (create relation). I want to pass vacancy_id to the new resume form, so relation will automatically be created after user fills in the form.

I have link_to tag, which passes vacancy_id. vacancy_id is not column in resumes table.

```
<%= link_to "React", {controller: "resumes", action: "new", vacancy_id: vacancy.id } %>
```

so link looks like

```
http://localhost:3000/en/resumes/new?vacancy_id=63606
```

How do I capture this parameter in controller. params[:vacancy_id] doesn't work.

Comment: That should be correct.  in your resumes controller in the new action, what do you see when you log or raise params?

Comment: Yes, that was correct, the problem was that, I didn't pass params from new to create action. I did it with session[:vacancy_id].